Nuxt js external multiple template js / css file import error
my problem is i can try my template import needed js and css files but dosnt work i try some roads like this
<script>
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      link: [
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/assets/css/vendor/vendor.min.css' },
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/assets/css/plugins/plugins.min.css' },
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/assets/css/style.min.css' }
      ],
      script: [
        { src: '/assets/js/vendor/vendor.min.js', body: true },
        { src: '/assets/js/plugins/plugins.min.js', body: true },
        { src: '/assets/js/main.js', body: true }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>



const stylesheets = [
  "/assets/css/vendor/vendor.min.css",
  "/assets/css/plugins/plugins.min.css",
  "/assets/css/style.min.css",
];
stylesheets.forEach(stylesheet => {
  let linkTag = document.createElement('link');
  linkTag.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
  linkTag.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
  linkTag.setAttribute('href', stylesheet);
  document.head.appendChild(linkTag);
});


i try some external files import but does not work on my page i need should to be a work my code

This is still the most relevant to the topic IMO: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/22016

Can you try using this in your nuxt.config.js file?
export default {
  css: [
    '~/assets/css/vendor/vendor.min.css',
    '~/assets/css/plugins/plugins.min.css',
    '~/assets/css/style.min.css'
  ],
  script: [
    '~/assets/js/vendor/vendor.min.js',
    '~/assets/js/plugins/plugins.min.js',
    '~/assets/js/main.js'
  ]
}

or if that doesn't work, use post-css import
<style>
    @import '~/assets/css/vendor/vendor.min.css';
    @import '~/assets/css/plugins/plugins.min.css';
    @import '~/assets/css/style.min.css';
    @import '~/assets/js/vendor/vendor.min.js';
    @import '~/assets/js/plugins/plugins.min.js';
    @import '~/assets/js/main.js';
</style>

please mark this answer as "accepted" if either of those worked for you

Probably not the way to go.

    <style>
@import '~/assets/css/vendor/vendor.min.css';
@import '~/assets/css/plugins/plugins.min.css';
@import '~/assets/css/style.min.css';
@import '~/assets/js/vendor/vendor.min.js';
@import '~/assets/js/plugins/plugins.min.js';
@import '~/assets/js/main.js';

Firstly thanks for the answers, this code work but only css files js files imported but everytime nuxt error,
So I Solve this problem i import all js files to public/ folder and i accessed directly this files i use useHEad(); statment here my code:
here my code
and files here:
here directory
